# ArangoDB aggregation counts of objects in array

Tags: aggregation, arangodb

I'm trying to generate facets (aggregation counts) for the following documents in a graph (based on collections rather than a named graph):

```
{
  "relation": "decreases",
  "edge_type": "primary",
  "subject_lbl": "act(p(HGNC:AKT1), ma(DEFAULT:kin))",
  "object_lbl": "act(p(HGNC:CDKN1B), ma(DEFAULT:act))",
  "annotations": [
    {
      "type": "Disease",
      "label": "cancer",
      "id": "cancer"
    },
    {
      "type": "Anatomy",
      "label": "liver",
      "id": "liver"
    }
  ]
}
```

The following works great to get facets (aggregation counts) for the edge_type:

```
FOR doc in edges
COLLECT 
    edge_type = doc.edge_type WITH COUNT INTO edge_type_cnt
RETURN {edge_type, edge_type_cnt}
```

I tried the following to get counts for the annotations[*].type value:

```
FOR doc in edges
COLLECT 
    edge_type = doc.edge_type WITH COUNT INTO edge_type_cnt,
    annotations = doc.annotations[*].type WITH COUNT INTO anno_cnt
RETURN {edge_type, edge_type_cnt, annotations, anno_cnt}
```

Which results in an error - any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: `WITH COUNT INTO` can only appear once in a COLLECT operation. It is possible to aggregate multiple values with `COLLECT ... AGGREGATE`, but it doesn't make much sense to build a simple sum twice or more, because it will be the same value as the grouping criteria are the same.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/arangodb/vNFNVrYo9Yo linked to from this Question: [ArangoDB Faceted Search Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221427/arangodb-faceted-search-performance/46323873#46323873) pointed me in the right direction.

```
FOR doc in edges
    FOR anno in doc.annotations
    COLLECT anno_type = anno.type WITH COUNT INTO anno_cnt
RETURN {anno_type, anno_cnt}
```

Results in:

```
Anatomy 4275
Cell  2183
CellLine  2093
CellStructure 2081
Disease 2126
Organism  2075
TextLocation  2121
```

Looping over the edges and then the annotations array is the key that I was missing.